# Python Treeview heading background colour with multiple treeview widgets

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, treeview

I am trying to change the background colour of one of the treeview widget heading. However, it changes for both the treeview widgets. I wish to have different background for the "Tree2" heading while not having any colour for "Tree1". What am I doing wrong?
Below is the code that I have.

Environment: Windows 10 19043.1165 Python 3.9.6

```
import tkinter as objTK
from tkinter import ttk as objTTK

# Create window
objWindow = objTK.Tk()

# Initialise variables
arrHdr = ["Hdr1", "Hdr2"]
arrData = ["Test1", "Test2"]

# ------------ Treeview 1
fFrame1 = objTK.LabelFrame(objWindow, text="Tree 1")
treeView1 = objTTK.Treeview(columns=arrHdr, show="headings")

treeView1.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="nsew", in_=fFrame1)
fFrame1.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
fFrame1.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

treeView1.heading(0, text="Hd1")
treeView1.heading(1, text="Hd2")

treeView1.insert("", "end", values=arrData)

fFrame1.pack()

# ------------ Treeview 2
fFrame2 = objTK.LabelFrame(objWindow, text="Tree 2")
treeView2 = objTTK.Treeview(columns=arrHdr, show="headings")

objStyle = objTTK.Style(treeView2)
objStyle.theme_use("clam")
objStyle.configure("Treeview.Heading", background="#c3c3c3")

treeView2.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="nsew", in_=fFrame2)
fFrame2.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
fFrame2.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

treeView2.heading(0, text="Hd1")
treeView2.heading(1, text="Hd2")

treeView2.insert("", "end", values=arrData)

fFrame2.pack()

objWindow.bind("<Escape>", lambda wExit: objWindow.destroy())

objWindow.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the modified code that works. Basically, the theme "clam" adds grey colour to the heading row. So I had to add "white" color to the first treeview as in code below.

```
import tkinter as objTK
from tkinter import ttk as objTTK

# Create window
objWindow = objTK.Tk()

# Initialise variables
arrHdr = ["Hdr1", "Hdr2"]
arrData = ["Test1", "Test2"]

# ------------ Treeview 1

objStyle = objTTK.Style()
objStyle.theme_use("clam")
objStyle.configure("treeView1.Treeview.Heading", background="white")

fFrame1 = objTK.LabelFrame(objWindow, text="Tree 1")
treeView1 = objTTK.Treeview(columns=arrHdr, show="headings", style="treeView1.Treeview")

treeView1.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="nsew", in_=fFrame1)
fFrame1.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
fFrame1.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

treeView1.heading(0, text="Hd1")
treeView1.heading(1, text="Hd2")

treeView1.insert("", "end", values=arrData)

fFrame1.pack()

# ------------ Treeview 2
fFrame2 = objTK.LabelFrame(objWindow, text="Tree 2")

#objStyle.configure("treeView2.Treeview.Heading", background="#c3c3c3")

treeView2 = objTTK.Treeview(columns=arrHdr, show="headings")

treeView2.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="nsew", in_=fFrame2)
fFrame2.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
fFrame2.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

treeView2.heading(0, text="Hd1")
treeView2.heading(1, text="Hd2")

treeView2.insert("", "end", values=arrData)

fFrame2.pack()

objWindow.bind("<Escape>", lambda wExit: objWindow.destroy())

objWindow.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add prefix to the style name "Treeview.Heading" to create custom style, otherwise it applies to all `Treeview`:

```py
objStyle.configure("my.Treeview.Heading", background="#c3c3c3")
```

Then apply this custom style to `treeView2`:

```py
treeView2 = objTTK.Treeview(columns=arrHdr, show="headings", style="my.Treeview")
```

Comment: This does not help. Somewhere I think I am missing the basics. Below is the modified code. I noticed that commenting out the line objStyle.theme_use("clam") does not colour the heading. Adding it colours both tree headings

Comment: I figured it out. Using "clam" theme adds grey colour to headings. So I changed the heading back to white for "treeview1" with this code. objStyle.configure("treeView1.Treeview.Heading", background="white")

Answer (score 0):

Modified code. Addin this as an answer as it does not allow to add code in the comment.

```
import tkinter as objTK
from tkinter import ttk as objTTK

# Create window
objWindow = objTK.Tk()

# Initialise variables
arrHdr = ["Hdr1", "Hdr2"]
arrData = ["Test1", "Test2"]

# ------------ Treeview 1
fFrame1 = objTK.LabelFrame(objWindow, text="Tree 1")
treeView1 = objTTK.Treeview(columns=arrHdr, show="headings")

treeView1.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="nsew", in_=fFrame1)
fFrame1.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
fFrame1.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

treeView1.heading(0, text="Hd1")
treeView1.heading(1, text="Hd2")

treeView1.insert("", "end", values=arrData)

fFrame1.pack()

# ------------ Treeview 2
fFrame2 = objTK.LabelFrame(objWindow, text="Tree 2")

objStyle = objTTK.Style()
#objStyle.theme_use("clam")
objStyle.configure("my.Treeview.Heading", background="#c3c3c3")

treeView2 = objTTK.Treeview(columns=arrHdr, show="headings", style="my.Treeview")

treeView2.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="nsew", in_=fFrame2)
fFrame2.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
fFrame2.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

treeView2.heading(0, text="Hd1")
treeView2.heading(1, text="Hd2")

treeView2.insert("", "end", values=arrData)

fFrame2.pack()

objWindow.bind("<Escape>", lambda wExit: objWindow.destroy())

objWindow.mainloop()
```